# MySQL Query Unexpected Results

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to run a MySQL query to return some information about the highest score for a group of games. The table is setup with the following columns in it: scoreid, score, gameid, playerid, date. When I run the following SQL command it gives me the proper high score but returns the first submitted playerid and date. What am I doing wrong here?

```
SELECT date, MAX(score) as score, scoreid, playerid FROM scores GROUP BY gameid
```

Comment: sounds a lot like this that was recently answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16531573/select-the-database-getting-all-the-maximum-values-of-a-column/16531740#16531596

Comment: what `date`, `scoreid`, `playerid` do you want to return when there is a tie in the `max(score)`?   A row for each?  arbitrary?  All possibilities collapsed into one row?

Comment: is a group of games truly represented by `group by gameid`?  Going by the name alone `gameid` sounds like a unique game , but could also represent a group of games, but i cannot tell without clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grouping by gameid, but you are returning some non-aggregated columns (`date`, `scoreid`, `playerid`). MySQL allows you to select non-aggregated columns in a group by query, but the value of those columns will be undetermined (it will usually return the first encountered value, but this is not documented and you can't rely on it). `Score` is aggregated (you are using `MAX()` which is an aggregation function) so its value will be correct.

If you want to return all rows that have the maximum score you should use a query like this:

```
SELECT date, score, scoreid, playerid
FROM   scores
WHERE  score = (SELECT MAX(score) FROM scores)
```

or if you want to return the rows that have the maximum score for every gameid, something like this:

```
SELECT date, score, scoreid, playerid
FROM   scores
WHERE  (gameid, score) IN (SELECT gameid, MAX(score) FROM scores GROUP BY gameid)
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44eee/4).

Comment: The second code nibblet you offered me did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The MAX(score) won't get the row that has the max score. It will simply return the max score, but all the other fields can simply belong to another row.

You can better try:

```
SELECT date, score, scoreid, playerid FROM scores GROUP BY gameid HAVING score = MAX(score)
```

Comment: why return the other fields ( `date`,etc) at all then @nl-x?

Comment: @gillyspy I don't understand your question. The OP has a query in where he tried to get the other fields related to the max(score). I don't know why he wants to have those fields.

Comment: this will likely exclude/skip entire gameids altogether (unless it's football where every score is 1-0 ;) ).   I doubt that is what op wants.  yes we need more clarity.

Comment: why this answer has so many upvotes? i don't think it will work http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/44eee/1

Comment: Gillyspy is actually correct, for some reason it is skipping out on entire gameid's. To clarify, I am trying to return the date, scoreid, and playerid that is in the same row as the max score. A gameid represents whatever game the score was for and game names are pulled from a different table. So there might be 5 scores for a specific gameid and I would like to display the top score for that gameid, and then also get the data for that date and playerid of that specific score.